# Get Description of Emoji Character

Tags: swift, string, character, emoji

Each Emoji has a description that you can see in Mac OS's `⌃⌘Space` special character picker. There's [a list of them here](http://www.grumdrig.com/emoji-list/). Is there a way for me to query for this description in code (short of entering them all into a Struct)?

I'd like to do something like:

```
let : Character = ""
let desc: String = .description
```

and have `desc` resolve to `"SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES"`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Core Foundation function `CFStringTransform()` has transformations that
determine the Unicode standard name for special characters. Example:

```
let c : Character = ""

let cfstr = NSMutableString(string: String(c)) as CFMutableString
var range = CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(cfstr))
CFStringTransform(cfstr, &range, kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName, false)
print(cfstr)
```

Output:

```
\N{SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES}
```

See http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/ for more information about
`CFStringTransform()`.

Comment: For Swift 2 and Swift 3 code, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37769025/1187415 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/42070725/1187415.

Answer (score 7):

With Swift 5, you can use one of the two following ways in order to get the description of an Emoji character.

---

### #1. Using `Unicode.Scalar.Properties`'s `name` property

`Unicode.Scalar.Properties` has a [`name`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081611-name) property. `name` has the following declaration:

```
var name: String? { get }
```

> The published name of the scalar.

The Playground code sample below shows how to use `name` in order to get the published name of a Unicode scalar:

```
let emoji: Character = ""
for scalar in emoji.unicodeScalars {
    print(scalar.properties.name)
}

/*
 prints: Optional("SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES")
 */
```

---

### #2. Using `Unicode.Scalar.Properties`'s `nameAlias` property

`Unicode.Scalar.Properties` also has a property called [`nameAlias`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081612-namealias) with the following declaration:

```
var nameAlias: String? { get }
```

> The normative formal alias of the scalar. [...] The `nameAlias` property is provided to issue corrections if a name was issued erroneously. For example, the name of U+FE18 is “PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRAKCET” (note that “BRACKET” is misspelled). The `nameAlias` property then contains the corrected name.

The Playground sample codes below show the difference between `name` and `nameAlias` for U+FE18 Unicode scalar:

```
let emoji: Character = "\u{FE18}" // ︘
for scalar in emoji.unicodeScalars {
    print(scalar.properties.name)
}
/*
 prints:
 Optional("PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRAKCET")
 */
```

```
let emoji: Character = "\u{FE18}" // ︘
for scalar in emoji.unicodeScalars {
    print(scalar.properties.nameAlias)
}
/*
 prints:
 Optional("PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET")
 */
```

Answer (score 6):

Martin R's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701154/2227743) using Core Foundation's `CFStringTransform()` still works, but the key feature actually comes from `kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName`, and in Swift 2 we can use it simply like this, by bridging with `NSString` and calling `stringByApplyingTransform`:

```
let c: Character = ""
if let result = (String(c) as NSString)
    .stringByApplyingTransform(
        String(kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName),
        reverse: false) {
    print(result)
}
```

> \N{SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES}

The same for a String:

```
let s: String = "This is a "
if let result = (s as NSString)
    .stringByApplyingTransform(
        String(kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName),
        reverse: false) {
    print(result)
}
```

> This is a \N{SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES}

Comment: For Swift 3 *and* Swift 4, see [@scott-gardner's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42070725/2227743) and Martin R's comment. Mine is only for Swift 2.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 version of **Eric Aya**'s answer:

```
let s = "This is a "

if let result = s.applyingTransform(
    kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName as StringTransform,
    reverse: false) {
    print(result)
}
```

> This is a \N{SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES}

Comment: Even simpler: `s.applyingTransform(.toUnicodeName, reverse: false)`