# How to find a textual description of emoticons, unicode characters and emoji in a string (python, perl)?

Tags: python, regex, perl, unicode, emoticons

The detection and counting of emoticon icons has been addressed [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149186/how-to-find-and-count-emoticons-in-a-string-using-python).

As a follow-up on this question and the solution provided, I'd like extend it with ability to link the detected emoticons, unicode characters and emoji to their corresponding (textual) descriptions:

- emoticons (Western and Eastern, e.g. List_of_emoticons from Wikipedia),
- unicode characters (e.g. U1F600.pdf available from the unicode website (direct link is included in the previous stackoverflow question mentioned above),
- other emoji types, e.g. from the list of emoji frequently used in Twitter (twitter-emoji-list from the emojipedia website).

Is there any comprehensive solution already available for conducting such a translation, in python or perl, similar to the method implemented in [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699576/get-description-of-emoji-character)?
If not, can you make a script that provides a textual description for an emoticon/emoji found in a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

perl example using [charnames](http://perldoc.perl.org/charnames.html):

```
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use charnames ':full';

my @faces = split //, '';
for (@faces) {
    say sprintf "U+%05X %s %s",
        ord($_), $_, charnames::viacode(ord($_));
}
```

prints

```
U+1F604  SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES
U+1F600  GRINNING FACE
U+1F608  SMILING FACE WITH HORNS
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has the [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata) import module with data on all the Unicode characters:

```
import unicodedata as ud
s = '\U0001F604\U0001F600\U0001F608'
for c in s:
    print('{} U+{:5X} {}'.format(c,ord(c),ud.name(c)))
```

Output:

```
 U+1F604 SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES
 U+1F600 GRINNING FACE
 U+1F608 SMILING FACE WITH HORNS
```