# How can I get the name of a unicode character in Swift?

Tags: swift, unicode

How can I get the name of a `UnicodeScalar` in Swift?

E.g. from [The Swift Programming Language - Strings And Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

"\u{1F425}" - FRONT-FACING BABY CHICK ("")

Is there an API to get that name "FRONT-FACING BABY CHICK" in Swift?

I remember seeing a solution, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699576/get-description-of-emoji-character

Comment: http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/ helped