# Is there a framework or function for turning emoji into words?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, emoji

I'm making an app which reads text aloud.
I want to be able to convert the emoji into speech as well by using their names.

So

-> Grinning Face

-> Smiling Face With Open Mouth and Smiling Eyes

-> Speak-No-Evil Monkey

And so on.

Is there a framework or function to achieve this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://grumdrig.com/emoji-list/) links to a repository containing the mapping from emoji unicode to description. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701154/1457385).

To read it out, get familiar with [AvSpeechSynthesizer](http://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/)